# Monotouch and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

I have a SQLite database with one table for cities name now I want to include this database to my monotouch project, connect to this database and select to this table. But I can find any tutorial to do this.

I don't new to create the database or create a new record. I just need to read the table.

Can anyone explain me how can I connect to my sqlite database an make a select.

Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE

```
using(var connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=zurfers.sqlite"))
            {                       
                using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
                    connection.Open ();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM City";

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

                        while (reader.Read()) {
                            wordCollection = (string[])reader ["Name"];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

include your DB file in your MonoTouch project and mark it as content.

```
using(var connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite"))
{                       
  using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    connection.Open ();
    cmd.CommandText = "this is my query";

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

      while (reader.Read()) {
        code = (string)reader ["ColumnName"];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jackson, but I'm getting the folliwing exception: Unhandled managed exception: SQLite error
no such table: City (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException). I checking the database with sqlite database browser and I have the table. Do I need to do something else? Thanks

Comment: Without seeing your code/db it's hard to say.  You can try "SELECT * FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';" to get all the tables in your db, just to verify that it reading the correct db file.

Comment: How are you including your db file?  If you just include it as content in your project, it will be copied into the root of your assembly, not PersonalFolders.

Comment: I added the file to my project and then build action > content

Comment: I updated using your code, and I still getting Unhandled managed exception: SQLite error
no such table: City